# Django admin always reset field value changes in docker container

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I am migrating and upgrading my mysql 5.5.X, python 2.7, django 1.11 web app on a ubuntu 14.04 machine to dockerized apps with python 3.7 on a ubuntu 18.04 machine. Everything seems working fine. However, when I change the field value in django admin, the changes always reset to original (10) after refreshing with Ctrl + R.

For example, there is a model field called search quota. The original value is 10. I change it to 15 or others in django admin. After that, I keep refreshing and the value will fall back to 10. Also, when I send several ajax requests to a python controller to deduct its value, it will restore to the original one. Why the changes are not persistent and how can I fix it?

Is it about my docker-compose config not correct? When I checked the logs, there are no error messages from the containers. Though I can see some warnings in db container.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.5.62
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - '3306'
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'bbbb'
      MYSQL_USER: 'aaaa'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'yyyy'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'xxxx'
  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      sh -c "exec gunicorn spo.wsgi:application --workers=2 --threads=4 --worker-class=gthread -b 0.0.0.0:8001"
           #
           # python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
           # python manage.py collectstatic --no-input &&
           # python manage.py migrate &&
    expose:
      - "8001"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/code
      - ./static:/static/
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    volumes:
      - ./static:/static/
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    links:
      - web
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

The Dockerfile for web container:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /var/www
RUN mkdir /var/www/code
WORKDIR /var/www/code
ADD requirements.txt /var/www/code/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-dev \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    build-essential \
    gcc \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libffi-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD ./ /var/www/code/
```

The requirements.txt file:

```
cffi==1.9.1
Django==1.11.26
gunicorn
django-cleanup==0.4.2
enum34==1.1.6
ipaddress==1.0.18
mysqlclient==1.3.13
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.2
Pillow==6.2.1
pyactiveresource==2.1.2
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycparser==2.17
pyOpenSSL==16.2.0
python-http-client==2.2.1
python-resize-image==1.1.19
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.19.1
sendgrid==3.6.3
sendgrid-django==4.0.4
ShopifyAPI==4.0.0
six==1.10.0
```

The db container logs:

```
db         | 191226 11:27:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db         | 191226 11:27:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
db         | 191226 11:27:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db         | 191226 11:27:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db         | 191226 11:27:45 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db         | 191226 11:27:45 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
db         | 191226 11:27:45 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db         | 191226 11:27:45 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db         | 191226 11:27:45  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
db         | 191226 11:27:46 InnoDB: 5.5.62 started; log sequence number 2377191038
db         | 191226 11:27:46 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
db         | 191226 11:27:46 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
db         | 191226 11:27:46 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
db         | 191226 11:27:46 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@d8024a779a88' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db         | 191226 11:27:46 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db         | 191226 11:27:46 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db         | Version: '5.5.62'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db         | 191226 11:30:50 [Note] mysqld: Normal shutdown
db         |
db         | 191226 11:30:50 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
db         | 191226 11:30:52 [Warning] mysqld: Forcing close of thread 2  user: 'songyang'
db         |
db         | 191226 11:30:52  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
db         | 191226 11:30:54  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2377714486
db         | 191226 11:30:54 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
db         |
db         | 191226 11:30:55 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
db         | 191226 11:30:55 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.62) starting as process 1 ...
db         | 191226 11:30:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db         | 191226 11:30:55 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
db         | 191226 11:30:55 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db         | 191226 11:30:55 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db         | 191226 11:30:55 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db         | 191226 11:30:55 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
db         | 191226 11:30:55 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db         | 191226 11:30:55 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db         | 191226 11:30:55  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
db         | 191226 11:30:56 InnoDB: 5.5.62 started; log sequence number 2377714486
db         | 191226 11:30:56 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
db         | 191226 11:30:56 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
db         | 191226 11:30:56 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
db         | 191226 11:30:56 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@d8024a779a88' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db         | 191226 11:30:56 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db         | 191226 11:30:56 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db         | Version: '5.5.62'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: Nothing you've shown here would obviously cause that behavior; it sounds a little more like a code-level problem than a deployment-level problem.  Are any of these containers restarting?  Can you include enough source code to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The containers are not restarting. They're up. I am not sure if it's code level or deployment level. When I check the general query log of mysql, I found that there were a bunch of update sql to be run, where I have no idea. I can include source code but the source code for django admin is only admin.py, which only includes list_display and list_filter for different models.